# Drop items from the beginning of the array inside a loop without mutating original array

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

so i am having a problem using javascript array splice where it changes the orginal array like

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){arr1.splice(i,1);}
```

in this above example , the arr1 gets changed after every iteration like :- [2,3,4,5]...[3,4,5]..etc

what i want to achive is :-

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    let arr2 = arr1.splice(i,1);
}
```

the result of this should give arr1 as [1,2,3,4,5] in all iteration ... but arr2 as [2,3,4,5]...[3,4,5]..etc ..... Basically, i want the splice function to not manipulate the original array but give the result in a new array and the original array remains the same during all iteration... is there any way to do this?

Comment: please add the result of the first iteratetion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return those partial arrays within common array (overwriting single variable as it is done by your code now doesn't make much sense) you may use [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) along with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const src = [1,2,3,4,5],
      res = src.map((_,i,s) => s.slice(i))
      
console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

If you need to do some further stuff with those partial arrays, you may either modify your initial code, like that:

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    let arr2 = arr1.slice(i+1)
    //log stringified arr2
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr2))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Or, make use of `Array.prototype.forEach` :

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
arr1.forEach((_,i,s) => {
  const arr2 = s.slice(i+1)
  // log stringified arr2
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr2))
 
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could slice the array with index plus one.

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(...arr1.slice(i + 1));
}
```